# How can i change the border of a react-select Select element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, border, react-select

I need to change the color of the border when the dark mode is active on my application, but i can't change the border color because it doesn't change with inline styling.
This is the code i have.

```
<Select 
    onChange={(e) => filtrarRegiao(e.value)} 
    placeholder="Filter by region"
    className={darkModeOn ? 'dark-lista' : 'lista'}
    style={{  }}
    styles={customStyles}
    components={{ ValueContainer, Placeholder, IndicatorsContainer, Group }}
    options={regions} 
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please checkout this codesandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shockley-02c9z?file=/src/App.js

After reading the official documentation, you need to pass object with

```
{control:()=>{ return { border: "1px solid black" } }}
```

to styles to use customize styles.

Comment: Ok, it kind of work but why does my placeholder goes outr of the select box when i style the border?

Comment: @PedroIgnacio sorry, not sure about it. Can you please provide a codesandbox link with all the code? I need to have a look at your code to further investigate your issue. If you think it helps please make this the accepted answer. Thanks a lot.